# jQuery UI Sort - two list and prevent sortable inside origin list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple example of jquery ui. Basicly i have to list of items, each one is sortable. And what i want to accomplish is the following: 
cancel sorting of the same list. with an example, if I click over an element on position one on list one, then drag it to position 6, and dropped. I want to prevent that, but if i drop the element in list two, that is ok.

i don't know how to specify, in order to fit my requeriments. ConnectWith seems not to be enough:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: [$('#sortable2')]
});

$("#sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: [$('#sortable')]
});
```

here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sQeZE/3/

Comment: You mean you *only* want to be able to take from list 1 and give to list 2?

Comment: yes, but prevent the sort if i drop the element on the same list as origin. Do I explain my self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be *exactly* what you are looking for, but you can bind to the `receive` and `stop` events (they trigger in that order).  `receive` indicates that a list item was received from another list.  When this is triggered, you can temporarily unblock sorting.  `stop` attempts to block sorting at all times:

```
var blocksort = true;
//Using jQuery 1.6.4, but use `.on` when available
$("#sortable, #sortable2").bind('sortreceive', function () {
    blockSort = false;
}).bind('sortstop', function (e) {
    if (blockSort) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    blockSort = true;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sQeZE/5/

Comment: Though my requirement was little different. This is the only answer which helped me to the right direction... Thanks a bunch :-)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to limit the containment of your lists to be the other list, like so:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: [$('#sortable2')],
    containment: $('#sortable2') });

$("#sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: [$('#sortable')],
    containment: $('#sortable') });
```

This makes it so that `#sortable`'s items can only be sorted within `#sortable2`'s list, and vice-versa

Comment: Good in theory, but `containment` also restricts sortable item movement so the effect is very jarring to the user.

Comment: it a good point, but my iu behaves in a strange manner. Thanks alot for your time and code.