# jQuery UI Sortable: limit allowed drops based on conditions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

First question, so please accept my apologies and let me know if anything here is breaking SO etiquette

I am working on a CMS page edit form with a variable number of file upload fields, but for the purpose of this question let's say there are 4 upload fields called *slots*. Each slot can accept only certain types of files, e.g.:

1. Accepts jpg, gif & png
2. Accepts png
3. Accepts jpg, gif & png
4. Accepts pdf

I'd like to allow users to rearrange uploaded files and am using jQuery UI's Sortable to accomplish this. Here's where I'm stuck. While dragging, files should only be allowed in slots with corresponding file types. So a jpg file in slot 1 could only be moved to slot 3, while a png file in slot 3 could be moved to either slot 1 or slot 2. A pdf in slot 4 should not be allowed to be moved at all.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/appel/59uzy/) demonstrating my set-up.

jQuery:

```
$(".slots").sortable({
  cursor: "move",
  placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
  items: ".slot",
  update: function (sorted) {
    // ajax magic omitted for the sake of brevity.
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="slots">
  <li class="slot accept-jpg accept-gif accept-png" id="sort_1">
    <div class="is-jpg">{jpg}</div>
  </li>
  <li class="slot accept-png" id="sort_2">
    <div class="is-png">{png}</div>
  </li>
  <li class="slot accept-jpg accept-gif accept-png" id="sort_3">
    <div class="is-empty"><input type="file" /></div>
  </li>
  <li class="slot accept-pdf" id="sort_4">
    <div class="is-pdf">{pdf}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any thoughts/ideas? Thanks in advance for trying help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try hooking into the recieve/over events on the connected lists.
See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14442218 for a similar question.

But I have no idea into which edge cases you might run.

Have a look here http://johnny.github.com/jquery-sortable/#limited-target for another sortable plugin, that gives you full control over which containers recieve drops. But since it does not support grids, it might not be for you.

Comment: Thank you, will have a look at your links.