# Don't allow sorting in a sortable list, only use connectWith to move them to a different sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery UI's `.sortable` feature. I have list a and list b. I want the user to be able to:

- Drag items from list a to list b but not from list b to list a
- Sort items in list b but **not** in list a

My code meets only meets the first requirement. I can't stop items being sorted in list a.

While the code in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14442218/5798798 automatically reverses any sorting done in a list, it doesn't prevent sorting within it all together (which is what I'm looking for).

```js
$("#sortable").sortable({
  connectWith: "#sortable2"
});

$("#sortable2").sortable({});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>List A</p>
<div id="sortable">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</div>
<p>List B</p>
<div id="sortable2">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g5nxjk0e/1/

*Note that there could be multiple lists that list a can be dragged into*

Comment: Don't use Sortable on List A. Use Draggable on List A. https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please review: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".drag > li").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sort",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $(".sort").sortable();
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>List A</p>
<ul id="drag-1" class="drag">
  <li>Item A</li>
  <li>Item B</li>
  <li>Item C</li>
</ul>
<p>List B</p>
<ul id="sort-1" class="sort">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<p>List c</p>
<ul id="sort-2" class="sort">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Blueberry</li>
  <li>Cherry</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How would it work if I had multiple sortable lists that I could drag list A to?

Comment: @TheCodesee you will need to use the correct selector: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-connectToSortable Consider using a Class selector that is applied to many sortables or list all the IDs. See update.